# Shrink confidence interval using a second estimator

Tags: confidence-interval

I have $n > 30$ samples from $X$ and $N >> n$ samples from $Y$.
I suspect that $Y$ approximates $X$ because $\bar y \approx \bar x$.

I want to create a 95% confidence interval for the true mean of $X$.
Can I use my large number of $Y$ samples to shrink the interval?

I'm not able to assume that $X$ and $Y-X$ are independent.

Edit for context: $X$ is the engine evaluation of chess positions at depth 22, and $Y$ is the analysis of a superset of positions at depth 19. I have found that $X_i\approx Y_i$ for $1\le i \le n$. I'm hoping we can use information from the $Y$ values (which are very cheap to generate) to shrink the confidence interval for $\bar x$.

Comment: Why would similarity of mean suggest that Y approximates X?

Comment: Good question, I also have qualitative reasons to believe Y approximate X.

Comment: You should probably mention the nature of your reasons in your question. It might help in guessing at a model for the situation. Similarity of the mean is - at least on its own - useless. You'll likely also need data of X,Y pairs in order to estimate the parameters of such a model.

Comment: See edit -- I do have the X,Y pairs. Samples from X are very cheap to generate.

Comment: Is this like a calibration problem then?